# How to get release notes programmatically from jira plugin

Tags: java, jira-plugin, release-notes

I am writing a simple listener for Jira 4.4.1 to manage release artifacts creation upon version release. Since it is a listener - I automatically have versionID.

How can I acquire release notes programmatically from within plugin?

Edit: I want to get access to the release notes report generated by Jira from a listener plugin [link](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Writing+JIRA+event+listeners+with+the+atlassian-event+library)

Apparently ReleaseNoteManager had this functionality, but it seems deprecated and I can find no documentation about how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do seems dubious, because [Maven JIRA Plugin hasn't been supported since 1.x.](http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/jira/index.html) This functionality, flatly, does not appear to exist.

Instead, use Maven Versions Plugin. You can find the documentation to get yourself started [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2010/08/18/managing-version-numbers-maven-maven-versions-plugin).

Comment: I do not use maven to build my project. I use ant.  I am not sure why are you suggesting maven at all (I have not mentioned it in my question).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at [maven changes plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changes-plugin/). It supports jira and various other issue management systems.